# SQL query that can display data with a null ID and with not null id on the same Datatable?

Tags: sql, select, join, null

Hello I have a question here...

I'll show you my tables first...

```
[Vendedores](
    [IdVendedor] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [IdGrupo] [int] NULL,
    [IdInfoContacto] [int] NULL,
    [ApellidoPaterno] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [ApellidoMaterno] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [Nombre] [varchar](35) NULL,
    [Estado] [varchar](10) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Vendedores] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 

[Clientes](
    [IdCliente] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [IdGrupo] [int] NULL,
    [IdVendedor] [int] NULL,
    [IdDireccion] [int] NULL,
    [IdInfoContacto] [int] NULL,
    [FechaAlta] [date] NULL,
    [ApellidoPaterno] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [ApellidoMaterno] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [Nombre] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [Empresa] [text] NULL,
    [Estado] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [Estatus] [varchar](20) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Clientes] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 

[dbo].[Mensajes](
    [IdMensaje] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [IdCliente] [int] NULL,
    [IdVendedor] [int] NULL,
    [CorreoRemitente] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [CorreoCliente] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [CorreosAdicionales] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Tema] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Mensaje] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Fecha] [date] NULL,
    [Hora] [time](5) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Mensajes] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 

[Archivos](
    [IdArchivo] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [IdMensaje] [int] NULL,
    [Nombre] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Ubicacion] [varchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Archivos] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

There are 2 ways to send messages in the system I'm developing...:

the first one is, you select a client, and when the message is sent, the client's ID (IdCliente) is taken from Clientes Table and inserted in a new row in Mensajes table.
that way, when you want to check all of the sent messages, you can clearly see to which client was sent.

the second one would be a free one, you send to whoever you want, you don't have to select a client. Therefore, when you register the new message, the IdCliente column would be null.

Some notes out of the way now: Vendedor is the seller or user who sent the message, Archivos means files, and in case you want to attach files, for each one of them, a new row in Archivos would be inserted and each with the same IdMensaje.

FOR THE moment, I have a query that allows me to see all my messages (with clients), and to also show how many files were attached to that message. HERE IT IS:

```
SELECT (Clientes.ApellidoPaterno + ' ' + Clientes.ApellidoMaterno + ' ' + Clientes.Nombre) AS Cliente, Mensajes.* FROM (SELECT Mensajes.IdMensaje, Mensajes.IdCliente, Mensajes.IdVendedor, Mensajes.CorreoRemitente, Mensajes.CorreoCliente, Mensajes.CorreosAdicionales, Mensajes.Tema, Mensajes.Mensaje, Mensajes.Fecha, Mensajes.Hora, COUNT(Archivos.IdArchivo) AS Archivos FROM Mensajes LEFT OUTER JOIN Archivos ON Mensajes.IdMensaje = Archivos.IdMensaje GROUP BY Mensajes.IdMensaje, Mensajes.IdCliente, Mensajes.IdVendedor, Mensajes.CorreoRemitente, Mensajes.CorreoCliente, Mensajes.CorreosAdicionales, Mensajes.Tema, Mensajes.Mensaje, Mensajes.Fecha, Mensajes.Hora) AS Mensajes JOIN Clientes ON Clientes.IdCliente = Mensajes.IdCliente ORDER BY Mensajes.Fecha DESC, Mensajes.Hora DESC
```

"(Clientes.ApellidoPaterno + ' ' + Clientes.ApellidoMaterno + ' ' + Clientes.Nombre) AS Cliente" Displays the full name of the client

however, now I want to have a query in which displays the same information as above... plus the following...

- Messages with IdCliente = null
- if IdCliente = null then the Cliente Column that I mentioned above would be "" (blank space)

If I need to be more specific, please let me know in what part must I give more information.

I hope you guys can help me
Thanks in advance

Comment: Rewrite your post, please.  There isn't an actual question, per se.  Also, you may want to post more attempts before asking people to write queries for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, change your JOIN to a LEFT JOIN:

```
LEFT JOIN Clientes ON Clientes.IdCliente = Mensajes.IdCliente
```

This will allow Messages with no associated IdCliente to remain.  To get the desired blank space, use COALESCE:

```
COALESCE(Clientes.ApellidoPaterno + ' ' + Clientes.ApellidoMaterno + ' ' + Clientes.Nombre, '') AS Cliente
```